# How to select log levels to the output of a bash script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

In the script i have written, the output is sent to a log file mySysMonitor.log. I want the user of this script to be able to choose what log levels(debug or info) to be sent to the log file. How do i do this. Take the script below as an example.

```
#!/bin/bash

processKD(){
  printf "\nCURRENT PROCESSES \r"
  ps -eo user,pid,pcpu,pmem,start | sort -rk 3,4 | head -n 11
  echo "TOTAL NUMBER OF RUNNING PROCESSES: $(ps aux | wc -l)"
}

loggedInKD(){
  printf "\nUSERS CURRENTLY LOGGED IN\r"
  echo "Number of users logged in: $(w | head -n 1 | cut -d"," -f 3)"
  who
}
processKd >> mySysMonitor.log
loggedInKd >> mySysMonitor.log
```

Comment: what would be the difference between debug and info level ?

Comment: I don't see anything in the example script about loglevels.

Answer (score 1):

you can use something like this;

```
#!/bin/bash

processKD(){
  printf "\nCURRENT PROCESSES \r"
  ps -eo user,pid,pcpu,pmem,start | sort -rk 3,4 | head -n 11
  echo "TOTAL NUMBER OF RUNNING PROCESSES: $(ps aux | wc -l)"
}

loggedInKD(){
  printf "\nUSERS CURRENTLY LOGGED IN\r"
  echo "Number of users logged in: $(w | head -n 1 | cut -d"," -f 3)"
  who
}



LOG_LEVEL="info"
#LOG_LEVEL=$1  #with parameter ./script info 

#LOG_LEVEL="debug"

if [ "$LOG_LEVEL" == "info" ]; then
loggedInKd >> mySysMonitor.log
fi

if [ "$LOG_LEVEL" == "debug" ]; then
processKd >> mySysMonitor.log
loggedInKd >> mySysMonitor.log
fi
```

Comment: Then the user will have to manually edit the script to change the log level. You'd be better off using parameters and setting your LOG_LEVEL varaible accordingly

Comment: Just tried running this. the log level of output isnt still debug only or info only. is there something i am missing